# ds.getConnection hangs indefinitely with tomcat 6 to MSSQL DB

Tags: java

I am trying to connect **mssql** database with my war file deployed on tomcat 6.0.41, java version 1.5.0_22.

Tomcat hangs for indefinite time at the following line of code.

```
DataSource ds;
this.conn = ds.getConnection();
```

And also it works fine with Oracle database.

I have tried making changes at tomcat in context.xml file but of no use.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate the DataSource initialization part?

Comment: public void setDataSource(DataSource ds)
    {
     try
  {
            log.debug("Setting connection"+ds);
   this.conn = ds.getConnection();
            log.debug("Connection made"+this.conn);
  } 
     catch (SQLException e)
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     
    } 
I dont think its code issue as its working fine with ORacle DB .I think its related to mssql DB compatiblity with jdk not sure.